# HTML5 / JS - Can I play two or more audio sounds simultaneously on iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, audio

I need to play two different sounds at the same time. I tried examples of [SoundManager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) and the [turntable](http://wheelsofsteel.net/) example, but non of the samples I tried haven't worked at all on Ipad 2.

Is it even possible to play more sounds simultaneously?

Answer (score 2):

Had developed HTML5/JS apps myself and I found out, that on iOS you can play only one sound at a time using HTML/JS... There are many weird things about the combination of sounds, HTML/JS and iOS... ([see here](https://getsatisfaction.com/schillmania/topics/ipad_weirdness_with_multiple_sounds)).

Comment: He has developed HTML/JS himself?

Comment: I'm not marking it as correct answer in the vain hope that somebody will come up with the solution :(